# How To Get Specific Value From LocalStorage Js

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I have this code where i stored some values into the browser local storage

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var obj = {
    "name": "hello",
    "price": 10000,
    "rate": 2020
};

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj));

var val = localStorage.getItem('cart');

console.log('value: ', JSON.parse(val));
```

it was stored successfully. 
But i don't really know how to get like only the name or the price only maybe something like ***obj.name***. Please how do i go about this

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
var obj = {
           "name": "hello",
           "price": 10000,
           "rate": 2020
};
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj));
var val = localStorage.getItem('cart');
var object = JSON.parse(val);
console.log('name: ', object.name);
console.log('price: ', object.price);
console.log('rate: ', object.rate);
```